# Modeling to avoid leaked_storage false positive

Tags: c, static-analysis, coverity

I'm struggling resolving a leaked_storage false positive. Given this example

```
struct string
{
  size_t len;
  data [1];
};

const char *string_new(const char *s, size_t n)
{
  struct string *st;

  st = malloc(offsetof(struct string, data) + n + 1);
  st->len = n;
  memcpy(st->data, s, len);
  st->data[len] = 0;
  return st->data;
}

void string_free(const char *s)
{
  struct string *st = (struct string *)(s - offsetof(struct string, data));
  free(st);
}
```

Coverity Scan will report

> Resource leak (RESOURCE_LEAK)5. leaked_storage: Variable st going out of scope leaks the storage it points to.

In this example, it direct to show that it doesn't leak. What can I do to silence the false positive?

Update 2020-May-7th

Modeling isn't the right technique. Coverity Scan does permit annotations to address this specific situation. In our case,

```
const char *string_new(const char *s, size_t n)
{
  struct string *st;

  st = malloc(offsetof(struct string, data) + n + 1);
  st->len = n;
  memcpy(st->data, s, len);
  st->data[len] = 0;
  /* coverity[leaked_storage] */
  return st->data;
}
```

will silence the false positive warning.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: st is pointer. you are access its members with (. operator) you should access with -> or (*st).len .   did this code pass compilation?

Comment: one more question where is the free() to st pointer returned by malloc??

Comment: That code stands no chance to actually compile, much less run. `st.<anything>` will puke the compiler, so I wouldn't be shocked if it also puked coverity.

Comment: @WhozCraig - You have choosen the right words to discribe this awful code. stackoverflow should block these kind of questions.

Comment: `offset` -> `offsetof`

Comment: Addressed comments in main post.

Answer (score 3):

Modeling isn't the right technique. Coverity Scan does permit annotations to address this specific situation. In our case,

```
const char *string_new(const char *s, size_t n)
{
  struct string *st;

  st = malloc(offsetof(struct string, data) + n + 1);
  st->len = n;
  memcpy(st->data, s, len);
  st->data[len] = 0;
  /* coverity[leaked_storage] */
  return st->data;
}
```

will silence the false positive warning.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: According to this: https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Suppressing-False-Positive-Intentional-defects, there are three ways to annotate: 

`// coverity[event tag:FALSE] `         - to classify the defect as False Positive
`// coverity[event tag]`                    - to classify the defect as Intentional
`// coverity[event tag:SUPPRESS]`   - to suppress the defect

If you want your "defect" to disappear completely, use SUPPRESS.

You can instead use a `#pragma` annotation which gives you the capability to generate a deviation report (see link).